# how pass the props from one component to another in react-ionic

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ionic-framework

I am passing the props from **Login** component to the **StoreView** component. when I am passing the props then getting a typescript error.

**TypeScript error**: *Type '{ data: Dispatch>; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'. Property 'data' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.*

my **Login** component

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
//more imports

const Login: React.FC = () => {
  //some states
  const [storeData, setStoreData] = useState([]);

  const loginUser = (event: any) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const loginApi = LoginAPI.userLogin(userEmail, password);
    loginApi
      .then((res) => {
        if (res) {
          setStoreData(res.store_id)
        }
        else {
          alert('invalid user')
        }
      })
  };

  return (
    <IonPage>
      <IonContent>
      <div className="login-container">    
        <div className="login-form-wrapper">
          Login please
          <form className="login-form" onSubmit={loginUser}>
            //my form data
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      </IonContent>
      <StoreView 
       //here i am getting error
       data = {setStoreData}
      />
    </IonPage>
  );
};
export default Login;
```

I wanted to pass my props to the **StoreView** component but getting error in **Login** component.

my **StoreView** component.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
//more imports

const StoreView: React.FC = () => {
    return (
      <IonContent>
          //here i want to my props data
       </IonContent>
    ); 
}  

export default StoreView;
```

Comment: Here is a [blog](https://fettblog.eu/typescript-react/components/) than can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define props type for the StoreView component.

```
type Props = {
    // do not use `any`, I don't know the structure of your data
    // you should create an interface suitable for the type of data you want
    data: any[];
}

const StoreView = ({ data }: Props) => {
    return (
      <IonContent>
          // do something with data
       </IonContent>
    ); 
}
```

Then you can use it like in your example (but you should probably pass `storeData` there, not `setStoreData`).

Answer (score 0):

For this small example i would suggest using React.Context to manage state between the two components.

Here is a [blog post using reactjs and ionic framework](https://dev.to/aaronksaunders/two-ways-to-manage-state-in-react-js-5dkb).

I would suggest also that you look at the [React.Context API Documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
//more imports

const Login: React.FC = () => {
  //some states
  const { storeData, setStoreData } = React.useContext(AppContext);

  const loginUser = (event: any) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const loginApi = LoginAPI.userLogin(userEmail, password);
    loginApi
      .then((res) => {
        if (res) {
          setStoreData(res.store_id)
        }
        else {
          alert('invalid user')
        }
      })
  };

  return (
    <IonPage>
      <IonContent>
      <div className="login-container">    
        <div className="login-form-wrapper">
          Login please
          <form className="login-form" onSubmit={loginUser}>
            //my form data
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      </IonContent>
      <StoreView 
       //here i am getting error
       // data = {setStoreData} <== this is wrong?
      />
    </IonPage>
  );
};
export default Login;
```

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
//more imports

const StoreView: React.FC = () => {
    const { storeData } = React.useContext(AppContext);
    return (
      <IonContent>
          //here i want to my props data
       </IonContent>
    ); 
}  

export default StoreView;
```